# Xubuntu wifi dont work Lenovo legion y530

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I have reinstalled linux many times(because sometimes nvidia proprietary driver purges system). Now its ok, but anything i tried to do for fixing wifi doesnt help.
I`m not very good with linux, so, please, write commands that can help you to understand what to do(sorry for my english, its not my main language)
I also have installed windows 10

## Weird solution

Load windows, reboot in linux. That works for me.

### Edit 1:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i rtw'
```

output:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)  
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822be
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)  
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38c2]
```

`dmesg | grep -i rtw`

output:

```
[    9.531403] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[    9.532679] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[    9.532682] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[    9.532683] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
[    9.532684] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[    9.538094] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
[    9.538109] rtw_8822be: probe of 0000:07:00.0 failed with error -11  
ls /usr/lib/firmware/rtw88
README           rtw8821c_fw.bin  rtw8822c_fw.bin
rtw8723d_fw.bin  rtw8822b_fw.bin  rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin
```

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact wifi device. Please run the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: 07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
   Kernel modules: rtw88_8822be
  08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
   Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38c2]

Comment: Now let's see: `sudo dmesg | grep -i rtw` It looks like you already have an installed driver!

Comment: [   10.045601] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)  
[   10.047438] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed  
[   10.047441] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac  
[   10.047445] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info  
[   10.047447] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup chip information  
[   10.117684] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13  
[   10.117775] rtw_8822be: probe of 0000:07:00.0 failed with error -114

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo   -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: output: sudo: 0: command not found

Comment: Please see my edit in a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibly useful discussion: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88/issues/37 A suggestion here is: **EDIT**

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtw_pci disable_aspm=Y disable_msi=y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtw_pci.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i rtw
```

Please edit your post to show the result.

I will further edit my answer to add additional troubleshooting steps if needed.

**EDIT 2**: Please try the solution here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462133

Comment: no such option in bios

Comment: in /etc/acpi/events/ i found "asus-wireless-on" and "asus-wireless-off"

Comment: Is the module loaded? `lsmod | grep asus` I doubt it on your Lenovo.

Comment: no, but ideapad_laptop is loaded

Comment: That is simply the module that translates key presses to action, in this case, turn on or off the wireless. Is your wireless hard blocked? `rfkill list all` If it is, press the wireless button to turn it on. On my Lenovo, it's Fn+F8.

Comment: no, its not hard/soft blocked

Comment: I have no other suggestions at this time. I will, however, continue to study.

Comment: i found  a weird [solution](https://gist.github.com/AnnoyingTechnology/45cbced6dd9e11fa714d3e0151be6717) ... All that you need is to boot in windows, then reboot in linux,  and then wifi starts working. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  Thanks for your answers.